# Communicate with EPP using wosa xfs

Tags: cen-xfs

I'm creating a program to communicate with the EPP like if I press any key the application should recognise it and print it back for now for illustration on how to create an application to communicate with the EPP.

Thank you.

I've found what I will call a function on "cwa 14050-6:2005" on page 42 "WFS_CMD_PIN_GET_DATA" and the description states that "This function is used to return keystrokes entered by user." My problem is writing or calling this function and when you go to page 43 on the output param "LPWFSPINDATA lpPinData;" which the "typedef" of it contains I will say a variable "lpPinKeys" which points to an array of pointers to WFSPINKEY structures that contains the keys entered by the user. So after going through this document I saw that in my case I need this, this is because when let's say I key in 1234 enter the application can be able to assign 1234 to a variable so that it can be verified and enter will cause the app to begin the keys verification to see if they match that's from database/server database and if they do then the app will call the relevant service else error will be displayed.

My main problem is calling this within my app. Even if the app can for now display back or assign the keys to a variable from a PIN pad (EPP). For now I don't use any encrypt just want to get and verify the plain keys.

Comment: Any help on how I can achieve this using C++?

Answer (score 0):

If you require EPP development for NCR machines, you have to use Key Library API. This is not a part of CEN XFS standard, but is explained in the NCR XFS documentation.

Comment: This is not true. You only need the Key Library if you want to create or modify the crypto keys. Normal keyboard usage is just "standard" XFS stuff. The only required thing is that the aggregate has been configured correctly.